# Copy, Paste and Clear a Table in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-8.1, worksheet-function, macros, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a workbook with 3 worksheets (Current Week, Meeting History, Last Week). The 'Current Week' worksheet has 3 tables in it. My goal is to copy one of the 3 tables to 'Meeting History', then clear the original table so that it can be used again the next day. The reasoning behind this is that I would like 'Meeting History' to be a hub for all the minutes throughout the week. I have a button with a macro attached to it right now that just clears the table and I'm hoping that this button can also copy the data to 'Meeting History' before it clears the table. How can this be achieved so that this can be done daily and by the end of the week I'd have a full 'Meeting History' sheet of info gathered/formatted throughout the week?

This is my current 'Clear' button macro. The information I'm trying to copy over is the information contained in G6-G12 and G14 - G18. The rest does not need to be copied but it does need to be cleared at the end of the day.

```
Sub Clearcells()
Range("F6", "F12").ClearContents
Range("G6", "G12").ClearContents
Range("H6", "H12").ClearContents
Range("G14", "G18").ClearContents
Range("H14", "H18").ClearContents
Range("H3", "H4").ClearContents
Range("H22", "H28").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to modify the existing macro, you'll have to copy and paste the code so we can add on to it.

Comment: @worthwelle I just updated my initial post with my current 'Clear' macro. I'm relatively new to macros within excel so I apologize if it seems rather juvenile and appreciate any help the community can give me.

Comment: You can simplify that code quite a bit by using `Range("F6:H12").ClearContents`. For copying to a different sheet, can you post a screen cap of the source and target ranges? Or at least tell us what range to copy to on the target sheet?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Awesome! I just simplified it and it worked great. As for the copying to a different sheet. I'm looking to take everything that is being cleared and to add it to the worksheet named 'Meeting History' Starting at B3 and going down. I'm also hoping that each day when the info is moved over, what is already there from the previous day will still be there, just maybe get moved down or something? I just don't want what get's moved over the day before to be deleted.  I'd like to post a screen cap but for some reason it wont let me upload one.